# Is there a Windows event to find out if a bluetooth device is getting paired

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I'm building an application that allows me to pair with a bluetooth device. 
Right now I'm trying to find an event in C# that allows me to detect when a device is being added or ready to be added (see img: Windows 10 popup)

[image]

Anyone know which one I'm looking for?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pair-devices, "Custom Pairing" section

Comment: This helped alot. Seems like the stuff I need is in the `windows.Devices.Enumeration` assembly.

Comment: There are few ways depending on your application type. For UWP you have to use Device Enumerator to be notified about changes in hardware. Custom pairing does not allow to handle pairing that appeared outside application. For classic application it is better to use Native Bluetooth API that allows to handle all events you need. Also you may take a look on Cofiguration Manager. Or capture WM_DEVICECHANGE message.

Comment: Ah yes, `windows.Devices.Enumeration` will only do me good in UWP, but I need it in a classic application. @MikePetrichenko what do you mean with Configuration Manager btw?

Comment: [CFG Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/develop/core/misc/system-center-configuration-manager-sdk). Or better use Classic Bluetooth API. Much better. Or simple Query WMI.

Comment: Well I tried overriding the WndProc method and try to filter out the Msg for WD_DEVICECHANGE, but for some reason I can't get it to trigger. It should be possible when a bluetooth device is trying to connect, I get a message, right?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late, but here are a few snippets about what I'm doing in plain Raw API (in C++), using the WM_DEVICECHANGE messages.

- you need to intercept WM_DEVICECHANGE messages (obviously)
- you first need to 'Register' the proper GUIDs:
- GUID_BTHPORT_DEVICE_INTERFACE {0850302A-B344-4fda-9BE9-90576B8D46F0} to intercept events about the Radio itself
- GUID_BTH_DEVICE_INTERFACE {00F40965-E89D-4487-9890-87C3ABB211F4} to intercept events about any Bluetooth devices and/or
- GUID_BLUETOOTHLE_DEVICE_INTERFACE
  {781aee18-7733-4ce4-add0-91f41c67b592} to intercept events about BLE
  devices.

(Those are 'Interface GUIDs' in case you need them with the SetupAPIxx/CM_xx routines)

I'm using the following code to 'register' them:

```
HDEVNOTIFY UDeviceInfoHandler::RegisterDeviceNotification(  HWND    hwnd,
                                                            GUID    InterfaceClassGuid,
                                                            DWORD   flags)
{
    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE DevFilter;
    ::ZeroMemory(&DevFilter, sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE) );
    DevFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof( DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE );
    DevFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
    DevFilter.dbcc_classguid = InterfaceClassGuid;
    return ::RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd,       //events recipient
                                        &DevFilter, //type of device
                                        flags);     //type of recipient handle
}

bool UDeviceInfoHandler::UnregisterDeviceNotification(HDEVNOTIFY hdevnotify)
{
    return TRUE==::UnregisterDeviceNotification(hdevnotify);
}
```

At this point, you'll be able

- to see 'Radio' appearing/disappearing (i.e by playing with the 'Activate Bluetooth' checkbow in Settings )
- to see the BT2.x virtual COM ports appearing/disappearing
- to see the BLE devices appear/disappear , PROVIDED they are already 'paired' (that is, in brief, added to the Registry )

by handling the

- DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL|DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE and
- DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE|DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE

messages in your WM_DEVICECHANGE handler.

If you need to access the DBT_CUSTOMEVENT messages pertaining to the Radio/Devices, you'll first need to 'Register' some 'events' for WM_DEVICECHANGE too, but for the 'HANDLE' of the Radio.
You can register the GUIDs of the following events

- GUID_BLUETOOTH_RADIO_IN_RANGE
- GUID_BLUETOOTH_RADIO_OUT_OF_RANGE
- GUID_BLUETOOTH_L2CAP_EVENT
- GUID_BLUETOOTH_HCI_EVENT
- GUID_BLUETOOTH_HCI_VENDOR_EVENT

Use something like

```
void UBthDeviceInfoHandler::RegisterBthNotifications(HWND hwnd,const UGuidItems& guids)
{
    BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS radio_params;
    radio_params.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS);

    HANDLE hRadio;
    HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND hFind = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&radio_params, &hRadio);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        do 
        {
            //for every events Guid you need
            HDEVNOTIFY hdevnotify=
                RegisterHandleNotification( hwnd,
                                            hRadio,
                                            Guid,
                                            DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
            if (hdevnotify!=NULL){
                  //insert code here
            }
            else{
                  //error handling
            }
            //end for
        } while (BluetoothFindNextRadio(hFind, &hRadio));

        BluetoothFindRadioClose(hFind);
    }
}
```

At this point, you'll be able to receive those events by handling the DBT_CUSTOMEVENT|DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE porting of the WM_DEVICECHANGE handler, with something like

```
    [...]
    #if (WINVER >= 0x040A)
            case DBT_CUSTOMEVENT:
            //@see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363217(v=vs.85).aspx
                if (lParam!=0){
                    PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR phdr = reinterpret_cast<PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR> (lParam);
                    switch (phdr->dbch_devicetype){
                        case DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE:
                            {
            //@see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wm-devicechange-messages

                                //typedef struct _DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE {
                                //  DWORD       dbch_size;
                                //  DWORD       dbch_devicetype;
                                //  DWORD       dbch_reserved;
                                //  HANDLE      dbch_handle;     // file handle used in call to RegisterDeviceNotification
                                //  HDEVNOTIFY  dbch_hdevnotify; // returned from RegisterDeviceNotification
                                //  //
                                //  // The following 3 fields are only valid if wParam is DBT_CUSTOMEVENT.
                                //  //
                                //  GUID        dbch_eventguid;
                                //  LONG        dbch_nameoffset; // offset (bytes) of variable-length string buffer (-1 if none)
                                //  BYTE        dbch_data[1];    // variable-sized buffer, potentially containing binary and/or text data
                                //} DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE, *PDEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE;

                                PDEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE phndl=reinterpret_cast<PDEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE>(phdr);
                                CustomHandleEvent(*phndl);

                            }
                            break;


                  default:
                        break;
                }
            }//endif lParam!=0
            break;
    #endif // WINVER >= 0x040A
```

the |dbch_eventguid| field being one of those GUID_BLUETOOTH_RADIO_IN_RANGE etc. events.

Well, this is only an overview of what I've discovered so far.
Any enhancements/suggestions/additions are more than welcome though.
I'm currently struggling with a few undocumented CUSTOM_EVENTS, whose GUIDs are

```
//When the Bluetooth radio handle is opened, call the RegisterDeviceNotification function and
//register for notifications on the handle using DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE as the devicetype.
//When registered, the following GUIDs are sent, 
//and the DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE::dbch_data member is the associated buffer.

//this unknow event happens while looking for nearby devices in Settings.
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_UNKNOWN_EVENT_GUID1,0x1BBD4010, 0x498C, 0x4E85, 0x85, 0x1B, 0xEA, 0xA0, 0x57, 0x15, 0xC3, 0x7A);

//
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_UNKNOWN_EVENT_GUID2,0xD4EB6503, 0xC001, 0x441A, 0xAE, 0x42, 0xEE, 0x0D, 0xC9, 0x6C, 0x18, 0x85);

//happening when opening Settings|Bluetooth panel
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_UNKNOWN_EVENT_GUID3,0x7A7637FF, 0x531C, 0x4205, 0x97, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x33, 0x5F, 0x65, 0xAD, 0xDD);
//nameoffset=-1 datalen=8

//Settings|Devices -> Bluetooth activation/deactivation
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_UNKNOWN_EVENT_GUID4,0xB74983CD, 0xC2D9, 0x4E38, 0xB8, 0x0E, 0x54, 0x72, 0xFC, 0x10, 0x8B, 0x4B);
//nameoffset=-1 datalen=8
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a device watcher.

Initialize with:

```
var deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector());
deviceWatcher.Added += DeviceWatcher_AddedAsync;
deviceWatcher.Removed += DeviceWatcher_RemovedAsync;
```

Then you get events on:

```
private void DeviceWatcher_AddedAsync(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
{
    ...
}

private void DeviceWatcher_RemovedAsync(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
{
    ...
}
```